# The timer flag is set immediately(Similary)

Tags: stm32, keil, hal

I am learning to use timer without interruptions(with flags). The STM32CubeMX generates the values configuration. But at the moment of initialization, it does not wait for the set time to be set automatically. I have seen in this and other forums they give solutions to problems that have interruption enabled. Try but It did not work for me. The only code I have written is in the loop.What I want to generate is that the led is off for 1 second and generate a small pulse when it is on but without interruptions, but I have realized that the timer does not even wait that second.UPDATE: Perform tests with the oscilloscope to see if there was a pulse, this through for (int e = 1; e <= 60000; e ++) that can be seen as a comment but even so the part in which the pin was in RESET state it was still practically nil.

```c
    #include "main.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim3;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  *
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    

    HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3);
        //__HAL_TIM_CLEAR_FLAG(&htim3, TIM_SR_UIF);
        //htim3.Instance->SR = 0;
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim3);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
        
while ( (TIM3->SR & 0x1)!=1)
{
    
}


    HAL_TIM_Base_Stop(&htim3);
    HAL_TIM_Base_DeInit(&htim3);
    
//for(int e=1;e<=60000;e++)
    //{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        //}
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
    */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV16;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV16;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

/* TIM2 init function */
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 100;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 4;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/* TIM3 init function */
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
{

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

  htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = 100;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = 625;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim3, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  if (HAL_TIM_OnePulse_Init(&htim3, TIM_OPMODE_SINGLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog 
        * Input 
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA4 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  file: The file name as string.
  * @param  line: The line in file as a number.
  * @retval None
  */
void _Error_Handler(char *file, int line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  while(1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( (TIM3->SR &= 0x1)!=1)
```

Not sure if this is causing the problem but I would be *very* circumspect about the use of `&=` here, it *changes* the value of `TIM3->SR`, clearing all but the least significant bit.

If you just want to *check* that bit without affecting any others, the correct way is with `&`, not `&=`:

```
while ( (TIM3->SR & 0x1)!=1)
```

---

Beyond that, there is at least one other possible problem. Specifically, while you have a (probable) delay between the GPIO reset and set *within* a loop iteration, there is no delay between the set in one iteration and reset in the *next* loop iteration. This means the set will be of a *very* short duration.

Comment: It does not work the problem remains the same.

Comment: Perform tests with the oscilloscope to see if there was a pulse, this through for (int e = 1; e <= 60000; e ++) which can be seen as a comment but even so the part where the pin was in RESET state was still practically nil and does not correspond to the programmed time.